# Toshiba laptop no sound after reinstalling th OS

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall

I have a Toshiba Laptop. By mistake I reinstalled the OS with mute on. Now there is no sound in the system.

Is there any way to get the sound back again?

EDIT:

I can see the volume icon in the system tray perfectly and nothing is mute anywhere. Everything else is also good.

But I am not able to hear any sound at all from the system. Even the booting sound or log-on and log-off sound is not there.

What I did was to reinstall the OS in mute mode and now I'm not able to hear anything. Is there any specific action which can be taken when somebody does the OS reinstallation in mute mode?

Answer (score 0):

When you look in the system tray (bottom right corner of the monitor) do you see one of the following icons? if so, which one?
[image: system tray]

if you do not see either of these icons then please go to your control panel and open Sounds and Audio Devices. On the Volume tab (the default tab) are either of the check boxes checked?
[image: volume]

if the check box for Mute is checked, un-check it and press ok and you should then be good. if they are both disabled or greyed out then go to the Audio tab. Is there anything in the Default device drop down for Sound Playback section?
[image: audio]

if there is nothing in the drop down and it is not disabled then select your default device and press OK. you should now be good. if the drop down is disabled, greyed out or if there is nothing in the drop down then you will need to install the drivers for your audio hardware. most likely they can be located on the Toshiba website if you know the model number of your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Toshiba's BIOS setting (during boot) to ensure the sound devices are enabled.  Here's how to get into the BIOS on several (not all) Toshiba laptops:

1. Turn on computer by Holding down power button while pressing the ESC key.
   The machine will beep, then display:
   Check System, then press [F1] key.
2. Release ESC key
3. Press F1 key

http://uk.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/faq.jsp?service=UK&FID=0000000401